# I have a confusion on some Python code. Both pieces of code give me the same answer

Tags: python, calculation

I have been practicing Python on [CodeChef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeChef). I come up with the solution, but somehow it gave me an error of *Time Limit Exceeded*. Other code that gives the same answer works fine which was submitted by other CodeChef members. What’s the difference between these two solutions?

My code

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    summ = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        summ +=i
        count +=1

    if summ%2==0:
        print(n)
    else:
        print(n-1)
```

---

Code submitted by another member of CodeChef:

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
  n = int(input())
  sumN = (n*(n+1))//2
  if sumN%2==0:print(n)
  else:print(n-1)
```

Comment: Using a loop to compute what you can get from a simple single formula is always going to be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you calculate the sum iteratively by adding each number from 1 to n, which requires n iterations.
In the other member's code, they use the formula (n * (n + 1) /2 ) to directly calculate the sum in constant time, without the need for a loop.
The time complexity of your code is O(n) because the loop runs n times, performing addition and increment operations in each iteration. As a result, for large values of n, it can take a considerable amount of time to calculate the sum and determine the result.

On the other hand, the other member's code has a time complexity of O(1) because the sum is calculated using a formula that doesn't depend on the size of n. This allows their code to provide the result more efficiently.

Comment: Technically more than O(1) because python's integers are not fixed width, but that does not take away from your point in any way.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since you've posted 6 answers in the last 40 minutes that appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your concern regarding making SOF a safe place. Now, addressing your concern about whether I am using AI-generated answers or not, please note that I only provide answers in areas where I have expertise. If I were using an AI tool, I would be able to answer every single question, wouldn't I? I'm not sure which tool you are using (possibly AI?), to come to this conclusion. Please consider taking this aspect into account as well, whether a person is bombarding answers outside their scope.

Comment: It is not believable. Can you please be honest? No one learns to use [articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) and change writing style overnight. Or become able to post two answers in less than 4 minutes. What kind of assistance did you use?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the program will run for N number of times when the N is less than, let's say, N=5.

It may run without any *Time Limit Exceeded* error if you run against a test case where N is very big. It fails and it can be optimized by using the sum of n natural numbers formula, i.e., N(N+1)/2